# Error while loading my admin controller

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have default controller and also admin controller. When i call my admin controller in admin folder i am not able to access it and getting 404 error.

```
routes.php
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/index';
```

http://localhost/codeigniter/ is loading basic controller.
http://localhost/codeigniter/admin is not loading the admin controller

```
Correct me where i am wrong.
```

Comment: What happens when you call  http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/admin

Comment: Unclear what you Asking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.php
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/admin/index';
```

As you already said it is in admin folder.
I am expecting hiearchy like this :

> Controllers->admin->admin.php

Answer Detailed explained:

```
$route['admin'] = 'admin(folder name)/admin(controller name)/index(function name)';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for this question, thanks for the replies.